# How to to use SQL Server application role in my connection string

Tags: sql-server, sqloledb

My current application uses very powerful credentials to access the SQL Server back-end database. I want to improve the security in my application by using an [application role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/application-roles?view=sql-server-2017) created.

For example, if I created one called `app-role`, with a password:

```
EXECUTE sp_addapprole @rolename = 'app-role', @password = `right pony duracell binderclip`
```

I want to enable the use of this application automatically during connection by specifying it in a connection string. I don't want to risk there being any places in the software that are accidentally not re-engineered to call:

```
EXECUTE sp_setapprole @rolename = 'app-role', @password = `right pony duracell binderclip`, @encrypt = 'odbc'
```

So obviously I want this to happen automatically during connection.

Bonus Chatter

The application roles feature was first added in SQL Server 2000.

Bonus Reading

- [How to to use SQL Server application role in my connection string](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28356988/How-to-to-use-sql-server-application-role-in-my-connection-string.html)

Comment: You can't set an app role in the connection string, but why not create a least-privileges user to connect to your database?  Application Roles are typically used to grant privileges that the credentials used to connect don't grant.  EG when end-users connect using Windows Integrated Auth.

Comment: That's exactly what i will be doing.